# Get data from another Excel file

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, windows-server-2003, vbscript

I have an Excel spreadsheet that contains a list of usernames

Each user will have the following code. I just need to find a way to substitute First.Last with the names in the Excel spreadsheet. There are over 800 names and I can do this manually. It is just very tedious.

```
echo Y | takeown /F "F:\Users\First.Last" /R
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /reset /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /inheritance:r /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /grant:r system:(oi)(ci)f /t /c /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /grant:r "Site admins":(oi)(ci)f /t /c /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /grant:r "Domain admins":(oi)(ci)f /t /c /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /grant:r "CREATOR OWNER":(OI)(CI)F /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /grant:r First.Last:(oi)(ci)f /t /c /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove:g "everyone" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove:g "administrators" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove Everyone /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove:g "COURTS\administrator.account" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove "COURTS\administrator.account" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\Users\First.Last" /setowner "COURTS\First.Last" /c /t /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /inheritance:e /T /C /Q
net share First.Last$ /delete
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove:g "system" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove "system" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove:g "Site Admins" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove "Site Admins" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove:g "Domain Admins" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove "Domain Admins" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove:g "Creator Owner" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\First.Last" /remove "Creator Owner" /T /C /Q
```

Comment: I suggest writing the data to a text file (e.g., CSV or tab delimited) and then working from that. P.S. Since your question involves running Windows commands, you should probably tag your question with the version of Windows that you are using (e.g., [windows-7]). Also, for good measure, what version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get a list of names from excel then copy and paste the list of names into notepad and save as **names.txt** as below.

pretend contents of names.txt

```
tim x
bob y
pete z
joe a
```

Goto notepad and paste this in:  (save it as **doit.bat**)

```
for /f "delims=@" %i in (names.txt) do @echo call perms.bat "%i"
```

This line will call the **perms.bat** for every username found in **names.txt**

If you want to do all users in f:\users*.* and forgo excel all together do this:
Instead of the for statement above.
Goto notepad and paste this in:

```
for /D %i in ("f:\users\*.*") do call perms.bat "%~ni"
```

save it and name it doit.bat

open notepad and place your code slightly modified.  Save and name it perms.bat

```
echo Y | takeown /F "F:\Users\%1" /R
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /reset /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /inheritance:r /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /grant:r system:(oi)(ci)f /t /c /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /grant:r "Site admins":(oi)(ci)f /t /c /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /grant:r "Domain admins":(oi)(ci)f /t /c /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /grant:r "CREATOR OWNER":(OI)(CI)F /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /grant:r %1:(oi)(ci)f /t /c /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove:g "everyone" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove:g "administrators" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove Everyone /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove:g "COURTS\administrator.account" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove "COURTS\administrator.account" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\Users\%1" /setowner "COURTS\%1" /c /t /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /inheritance:e /T /C /Q
net share %1$ /delete
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove:g "system" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove "system" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove:g "Site Admins" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove "Site Admins" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove:g "Domain Admins" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove "Domain Admins" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove:g "Creator Owner" /T /C /Q
icacls "F:\USERS\%1" /remove "Creator Owner" /T /C /Q
```

goto adminstrative command prompt.

If you want to execute this in real time do this:

type **doit.bat**

If you want to save the commands to a file:

```
for /f "delims=@" %i in (perms.bat) do echo echo %i ^>^>all.txt  >>txt.bat
```

backup **perms.bat** else where.  Then rename txt.bat to **perms.bat** and execute **doit.bat** 
Then when you run **doit.bat** all the commands will appear in plain text in **all.txt**.
You can then copy and paste the results into excel if you need to.